Access private Apt repository on Google Cloud by access restricted URL
I have created an Apt repository on Google Cloud for hosting Debian packages. The goal is to have private access from the internet by using an access token / private key or similar to this repo. The machines accessing the repo are standard machine with no relationship to Google Cloud and they have no gcloud and gcloud credentials. What are the options to access the repo? Or how can a private Apt repo be hosted on Google Cloud if this does not work (without doing it the manual way)?

By restricting access with an access token or private key, you can obtain private access to your Apt repository on Google Cloud in a few different methods without requiring gcloud credentials on the devices.
Depends on your needs and requirements. Consider factors such as your security needs, budget  and desired level of control and take any of the below method :

Using Cloud Storage with Signed URLs : Your Debian packages should be uploaded to a cloud storage bucket. Give a certain service account read access to the bucket and create Signed URLs with expiration dates for objects in the bucket. Sent these verified URLs to the machines requiring repository access.

Using Artifactory Repository with IAM Authentication : Use the managed service Google Artifact Registry to store packages and container images. Make sure your Debian packages are stored in a private repository. To provide access to particular service accounts, configure access control Using IAM policies. These credentials can be used by machines to access the repository.

Using Cloud Functions : Create a Cloud Function that serves as a safe entry point to the packages stored in your cloud storage bucket. Tokens and certificates can be used by the function to manage authentication. The function offers a temporary download URL for the requested  package, If authentication is completed.


EDIT 1 :
While being a strong choice to manage private packages, the Artifact registry is not directly integrated with the apt tool which is standard on Debian systems. For your private repository, you may still utilize the Artifact Registry, and on the client machines, you can use a specific tool to access the packages.
As per official GCP document on Manage Debian packages:

“Artifact Registry supports Debian packages that you manage with Apt”.
For your Debian packages, you must first establish a private
repository in the Artifact Registry.

Assign the required IAM permissions to a service account that will be used for authentication (roles/artifact registry.reader, for example).
Install the Docker tool or similar tool which are compatible with the Artifact Registry on the client machines. Refer to this official GCP document on pushing and pulling container images with Docker for more information.
EDIT 2
That’s right, the previous answer uses docker for authentication but it is not directly relevant. For this one, I will give you a relevant approach that utilizes IAM authentication with a private Artifact Registry repository and Curl as a tool.
Setting up IAM Authentication:
Go to Google Cloud Console > IAM Admin-Service Accounts. Click on it and create a new service account so that you can access the repository.
Assign roles like artifact registry etc.Then read service accounts by readers. This gives Read access to your own artifact Registry repository.
You need to download the JSON Key file of this service account because it contains the authentication credentials.
Next, base64 encodes the content of the JSON key file obtained in the previous step. You can use base64 or any other tool which you are comfortable with to do this encoding. This encoded text is required for the authorization header.
Encoded _key = $ (base64 key _file.json)
Now, there is an additional permission header that needs to be added for curl command i.e authorization: bearer <encoded_key>
After adding the authorization header along with an encoded key ;  A package from your Artifact registry repository can be downloaded using curl.
Following above steps allow you to download packages from your private Artifact registry repository on machines using only curl and service account credentials , without gcloud or docker.
Refer to this document by JFrog for more information about  using cURL with an access token

Thanks. Only option 2 seems to be what I need. But does does e.g. a curl command looks like when using such an IAM account to download a package? And what is supported by apt?

@ K_o_ I have edited my answer. I am happy to hear that  Using Artifactory Repository with IAM Authentication helps you. If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as upvote and accepted for the greater visibility for the community

"These credentials can be used by machines to access the repository." How? What is the format to execute the authentication? TLS? OAuth? What is the curl example command line for this? The additional comment refers to Docker. I do not see how this is related. The answer should be a concrete solution and show the steps.

@ k_o_ I have edited my answer. It helped you to solve your issue?  If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as upvote and accepted for the greater visibility for the community
